# Display bounding boxes in Apple AR SceneKit

Tags: swift, object-detection, scenekit, arkit, bounding-box

I am using YOLOv3 with Apple Vision to classify objects during my AR SceneKit session. I want to render the bounding boxes of the detected objects in my screen view. Unfortunately, the bounding boxes are are placed too far down and have a wrong aspect ratio. Does someone know what the issue might be?

This is how I am currently transforming the bounding boxes.
Assumptions:

- The app is in portrait mode
- Vision request is performed with centerCrop and orientation .right.

Fix the coordinate origin of vision:

```
let newY = 1 - boundingBox.origin.y
let newBox = CGRect(x: boundingBox.origin.x, y: newY, width: boundingBox.width, height: boundingBox.height)
```

Undo center cropping of Vision:

```
let imageResolution: CGSize = currentFrame.camera.imageResolution
// Switching height and width because the original image is rotated
let imageWidth = imageResolution.height
let imageHeight = imageResolution.width
// Square inside of normalized coordinates.
let roi = CGRect(x: 0, y: 1 - (imageWidth/imageHeight + ((imageHeight-imageWidth) / (imageHeight*2))), width: 1, height: imageWidth / imageHeight)
let newBox = VNImageRectForNormalizedRectUsingRegionOfInterest(boundingBox, Int(imageWidth), Int(imageHeight), roi)
```

Bring coordinates back to normalized form:

```
let imageWidth = imageResolution.height
let imageHeight = imageResolution.width
let transformNormalize = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0 / imageWidth, y: 1.0 / imageHeight)
let newBox = boundingBox.applying(transformNormalize)
```

Transform to scene view: **(I assume the error is here. I found out while debugging that the aspect ratio of the bounding box changes here.**)

```
let viewPort = sceneView.frame.size
let transformFormat = currentFrame.displayTransform(for: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: viewPort)
let newBox = boundingBox.applying(transformFormat)
```

Scale up to viewport size:

```
let viewPort = sceneView.frame.size
let transformScale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: viewPort.width, y: viewPort.height)
let newBox = boundingBox.applying(transformScale)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

[Picture of incorrect bounding box on a bottle of water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8aTd.jpg)